# Can you use rectifiers from different transformer sources in parallel?

Tags: power-supply, transformer, parallel

Consider following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTKPz9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It uses two transformers, rectifies their output separately (so that they can't interfere), filters the `|sin(x)|` using capacitor and then uses combined power of both transformers.

I can't see any problem with this design, however so far I learned that using power sources in parallel does never work well.

So is this design also flawed?

Comment: What is the design trying to achieve with these 2 supplies? Load sharing? Redundancy?

Comment: I have multiple low voltage transformers (12V). However, they are small and do overheat when I use them for electrolysis. Currently, I'm switching one on and off to avoid burning it. I'd preffer to use all at once to get more current and avoid overheating. Also more separate mass means better cooling.

Comment: Your circuit will work - it won't explode or anything like that.  The amount of current drawn from each source isn't controlled by your design though, so it might not share the load very well between them.

Comment: I wasn't afraid of explosion, but of a power loss - similarly the way power is lost when you connect batteries in paralel - you get more current, but some current is lost by batteries discharging over each other.

Comment: Bridge rectifiers are OK because they are made of diodes.  If the output of BR1 goes higher than the output of BR2 then current still won't flow from BR1 into BR2.

Comment: I tried it and the rectifiers started to heat suspitiously. There might be other reason - but are you really sure this is ok?

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, but it's usually good to wait a while to see what several people have to say before deciding which to accept.  Others are less likely to answer or even read a question that already has a accepted answer.

Comment: You're right, but I was already googling and thinking about it, and I think there's not much more to say to the topic. I also often forget to accept while waiting for *better answer*. I found your answer helpful. I'll unaccept and wait though, maybe somebody will come with some math related to the topic.

Comment: If you want someone to show calculations, you have to give us some numbers to work with. Right now there is nothing to calculate. You haven't said what the open circuit voltage of the transformers are, what the load current is, and how much the voltage sags with one transformer at full load.  Without numbers from you, we can only talk in generalities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you show will work in that no harm is done and you will get a DC voltage out.  This might be a reasonable design if one or the other tranformer might not be powered sometimes, and you want the system to work when either is powered.

However, if you are expecting twice the current output, then it might not work so well.  Two transformers, even of the same model, will have a little different output voltage.  One of them will take more of the load.  The impedance of each transformer will help balance the load, but you can't count on 50% for each.  How much you can count on load sharing has to do with the transformer impedances and the expected part to part variation.  If the transformers are different models, then you should size everything so that each one can supply the full current by itself.

Comment: I actually just need to lower the load *a little*, so that the cooling is sufficient and the device can run without pauses. So it might not be necessary to get a 50/50.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I agree. The proposed circuit is more like two power sources connected redundantly, in case one stop working, the other can support the supply to the load

Answer (score 1):

To balance the load between those two transformers/rectifiers, you can install one very low-value resistor between each rectifier bridge's (+) terminal and the final common (+) output instead of connecting them directly.

Comment: An inductor would be better - an Inter-phase Transformer as they are referred to when you deal with multi-pulse rectifiers.

Comment: @JonRB, if installed at the rectified & filtered end where it's all DC, I'm not sure that an inductor would buy you much.

Comment: There already are separate resistances in there which already do balance the load to some extent.  These are the effective DC resistances of the transformers as seen by looking into the secondaries.  If these are large enough, then no deliberate additional resistance is needed.  The problem is the OP hasn't given us any specs on transformer impedance, mismatch of open circuit voltage, and current requirements of the load, so we can't know what additional may be needed.